# how to understand previous url

Tags: django, url, django-views, django-urls

Is there a way to understand the previous url in django view? I mean how can become aware from which url(page in my site) user is coming to this url? i've found doing this in template, but i want to know it in views.

```
def func(request):
   if request.is_ajax():
      //if the last url was the url of this page, do s.th
      //else do s.th else
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By checking the referer, the new webpage can see where the request
>   originated.

```
req.META['HTTP_REFERER']
```

should do the trick.